# Latex, left margin align equation in a longtable

Tags: equations, align, margins, longtable

I've created a longtable in latex, and I've centred it, because it is quite wide, and I don't want my text running off the side.
However I have one particularly long equation, which I put in the align block, so it goes down into a new line. However unlike the rest of the equations in column 1, it doesn't start at the same place as the others (which is the left of the margin).

I have tried using the same method as shown here, but that doesn't work. [Latex longtable, start equation on new line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337964/latex-longtable-start-equation-on-new-line)

I'm wondering how I can make it start on at the margin, and also how to remove the [t]

My code and a print screen of my pdf is below:

[image: Column 1, row 5 the equation doesnt start in the same place]

As you can see from the picture above, column 1, row 5 (with the red text), the equation doesn't start at the same point as the others. And also the [t] is there. Any way to remove it would also be helpful.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering}m{5cm}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.5mm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% all relevant preamble above %

\begin{document}
...
...
\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\begin{longtable}{ >{$}l<{$} L >{$}l<{$} }
\centering
....
more similar
....

\overline{X} \cdotp Y \cdotp Z + [(\overline{X} + Y + Z) \cdotp (\overline{X} + \overline{Y} + \overline{Z})]  & 
Multiply everything out} & 
\begin{aligned}[t]
A \cdotp B = \overline{A} + \overline{B},
& \quad A = \overline{X} + Y + Z \\ 
& \quad B = \overline{X} + \overline{Y} + \overline{Z} 
\end{aligned} \\

\begin{aligned}[l]
\overline{X} \cdotp Y \cdotp Z + [\textcolor{red}{\overline{X} \cdotp    \overline{X}} + \overline{X} \cdot \overline{Y} + \overline{X} \cdot \overline{Z} + \\ 
                              Y \cdotp \overline{X} + \textcolor{red}{Y  \cdot \overline{Y}} + Y \cdot \overline{Z} +
                              Z \cdotp \overline{X} + Z \cdot  \overline{Y} + \textcolor{red}{Z \cdot \overline{Z}}]  
\end{aligned}[t] & 
Use De Morgans's law [OR to AND] across 3 variables, twice. & 
\overline{A+B+C} = \overline{A} \cdotp \overline{B} \cdotp \overline{C} \\
 ....
 more similar rows
 ....
 \end{longtable}
 \endgroup
 ...
 ...
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Tha same question was already asked *user118173 *. See answer on it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337964/latex-longtable-start-equation-on-new-line

Comment: That's the method I used, but it doesn't work. In fact I'm the one who asked that question but, I accidentally made a different account for it, I was unaware I had this one.

Comment: well, do you now test my answer in given link? does it help you? Let me know in comment below answer, not here.

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. It was to do with where I put my \\ in the text. Thank you, your method did work.